# Как выровнять первую строку текста по центру в CSS (задать для неё одинаковые отступы как на макете)?

Tags: css3, html5

Всем привет!

[image: у меня есть psd макет:]

Вот фрагмент моего кода на html и css:

```css
header {
  background-color: #87509c;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
    p {
  padding: 147px 97px 67px 97px;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2.63em;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f7f3ea;
}
```

```html
<header>
     <p>Hi there! We are the new kids on the block
                    and we build awesome websites and mobile apps.</p>
</header>
```

[image: Вот результат:]

Подскажите, как выровнять по центру первую строку текста (задать для неё одинаковые отступы как на макете)?

Comment: Если будете использовать те же шрифты, что и в макете, то проблема исчезнет сама собой, скорее всего.

Comment: Вы имеете в виду отступы?

Comment: У Вас на на двух скриншотах разные шрифты. Разные шрифты имеют разную ширину символов, поэтому перенос на первой строке происходит не в том месте, где ожидаете. А так всё правильно - и там и там `text-align: center;` и никакого отступа в первой строке.

Answer (score 0):

```
header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #87509c;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    color: #ffffff;
}

p {
    padding: 147px 0 67px;
    width: 1000px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-align-last: justify;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 2.63em;
    color: #f7f3ea;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: #87509c;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

header p {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3.6vw;
  text-align: center;
  color: #f7f3ea;
  max-width: 80%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <p>Hi there! We are the new kids on the block and we build awesome websites and mobile apps.</p>
</header>
```