# Разместил на странице изображение, но его углы закруглись, хоть в css-коде нет никакого связанного с этим стиля

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

Само изображение имеет прямые углы, то есть дело не в нем.Если открываю инспектор кода страницы, то появляется скругление border-radius: 0.25rem;. Не могу понять почему, ведь никаких border-стилей я не задавал.Вот HTML:

```css
.section-info {
  padding-left: 120px;
  padding-top: 140px;
}

.cards {
  max-width: 1110px;
  padding-top: 102px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  /* перенос на след строку */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.card {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/D37fO.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 360px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.card:hover {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 95, 163, 0.65), rgba(0, 95, 163, 0.65)), url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/D37fO.png);
}

.card-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 27px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #FFFFFF;
  padding-top: 261px;
  padding-left: 45px;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <div class="card-text">
    <p>Бухгалтерское <br>обслуживание</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: не круглая,3 раза уже проверил

Comment: если вы такого не писали, значит вы что-то стороннее подтягивете в проект. и в css у селекторов классов должна стоять точка перед именем.

Comment: @MaximLensky: 100% родитель у `.card` имеет скругление. Не зря же он `absolute`. А вот картинка, думаю, тут ни причём.

Comment: @MaximLensky: тогда, скорее всего прав Андрей - сторонние стили.

Comment: не получается загрузить картинку

Comment: @UModel сейчас проверю

Comment: @ghvbty надо больше стилей скинуть

Comment: @ghvbty тут на сайте есть фрагмент кода, где можно прямо на stackoverflow воспроизвести html/css/js. Загрузите в него, будет удобнее. пример: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1123720/331312

Comment: @МихаилКамахин секунду

Comment: @UModeL мне уже самому интересно - что же чёрт возьми закругляет картинку - я попытался воспроизвести - https://codepen.io/topicstarter/pen/dyYKbGa и ни чего картинку не закругляет

Comment: закругления нету

Comment: И на `hover` нужно менять `background-image`, а не весь `background`

Comment: окей, скорее всего @AndreyFedorov прав, что-то стороннее его редактирует,возможно normalize.css+ у меня еще owl-carousel на сайте есть, может она что-то редактирует
в любом случае всем спасибо за потраченное время

Comment: @UModeL благодарю

Comment: @ghvbty так консоль браузера показывает все стили и их источники. Достаточно отключить всё и посмотреть, какие стили влияют на скругление краёв и откуда они берутся. Вот пример для ruSO на скругление аватарки в правом нижнем окне стилей (google chrome): https://i.stack.imgur.com/sMBi8.png

Comment: @AlexKrass вот спасибо,ты конечно зарешал, это все бутстраповский css редактировал